# DRY view for sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

In my quest to keep my application views as DRY as possible I've encountered a little snag. My appliation.html.erb incorporates a static sidebar menu. Each of my main controllers incorporates a secondary sidebar menu (essentially a submenu). I can take the code that renders the menu out of application.html.erb and put it in each of my views and change the secondary sidebar there, but this produces a lot repetition in my views.

I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126238/need-advice-structure-of-rails-views-for-submenus) and looked at [this page](http://pothibo.com/2014/04/contextual-menus-with-yield-and-content_for/), but I was unable to get either idea to work. I was thinking that I could put something like:

```
<% provide(:submenu, 'layouts/sidebars/sidebar_customers_contacts') %>
```

at the top of each view and use that to render the associated partial by doing

```
<% content_for(:submenu) do %>
   <%= render :partial => :submenu %>
<% end %>
```

from the application.html.erb but of course that didn't work.

This is my current application.html.erb:

```
  <div class="side">
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebars/sidebar_dashboard' %><!-- this needs to load a sidebar based on the controller that calls it. Each view of the controller will get the same sidebar.  -->
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
```

I feel like I'm making this more difficult than it really is. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails provides a helper called `controller_name` which you can read more about [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class).

Assuming you adhere to your own naming conventions, this should work as-is. If you decide some controllers don't get a sidebar, you may need to throw in some conditionals...

**application.html.erb**

```
<div class="side">
  <%= render "layouts/sidebar" %>
  <%= render "layouts/sidebars/#{ controller_name }" %>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, my mistake was using single quotes instead of double-quotes. You cannot use #{string interpolation} within single quotes. [Source](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/60278)

Comment: Thanks @Lenny Bose. This is perfect if I can get it to work. I tried controller_name, controller.controller_name, '@controller.controller_name' and I get 'The partial name (layouts/sidebars/#{ controller_name }) is not a valid Ruby identifier' for each one. is my syntax incorrect? I am using syntax shown in the answer and even some variations of it. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error points in the right direction. Rails wasn't interpolating the controller name into its value, but rather was just using the variable name. My edit above should work.

Comment: Awesome! That was about the only variation I hadn't tried and of course it is the only one that works. : ) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy Rails-ing!